# vba from 2 different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to be able to loop through all rows on my first table to get some data from the second sheet with vba.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

On Error Resume Next
searches = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(ws1.Range("$A"), ws2.Range("$A:$B"), 1, False)
On Error GoTo 0
If (IsEmpty(searches)) Then
    ws1.Range("$C").Formula = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Else
    ws1.Range("$C").Value = searches
End If
```

It does not let me pass the entire Range which is C column from Sheet1.

Comment: Just use `Range("C")`

Comment: The first item in a look up must be a single cell or value. Think is should be `range("C:C")` anyway, though do you really need to insert it into 1m cells?

Comment: Also your lookup is only ever going to return the value you're looking up because your column number is 1.